# Are there fast rank and unrank algorithms for integer vectors under the action of a permutation group?

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, bijective-combinatorics

We are distributing $m$ indistinguishable balls in $k$ numbered boxes $S=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. A distribution is a tuple of nonnegative integers $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ whose sum is $m$. We also have a permutation group $G$ acting on $S$, and two distributions $a,b$ are considered equivalent, if there is a permutation $g \in G$ such that $b_i = a_{g(i)}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k$. Denote the set of the equivalence classes by $V$. An equivalence class can be represented by some canonical element of it, for example the distribution that comes first in reverse lexical order.

> **Question:** Are there known fast rank and unrank algorithms for $V$?

A [rank function](https://oeis.org/wiki/Ranking_and_unranking_functions) is a bijection $r : V \to \{1,\ldots,\lvert V\rvert\}$, and its inverse $u$ is an unrank function. So the unranking $u(i)$ gives "the $i$th member", in some linear order, and the ranking tells the index of a given member.

By "fast" I mean clearly faster than iterating the distributions in a linear order until a match is found. Let's say a "fast" unranking $u(i)$ takes time $O(\lvert V \rvert^\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a constant, $0 \le \alpha < 1$. The naive iteration takes time $\Omega(\lvert V \rvert)$ when accessing the last element ($i = \lvert V \rvert$).

### Some observations and related problems

- The *counting* problem is well understood: $\lvert V \rvert$ can be efficiently calculated using the cycle index theorem, a.k.a. Pólya counting (see e.g. [this blog post](https://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/2018/03/16/a-counting-problem/))
- The *iterating* problem is also well understood: there are nice algorithms for going through $V$ in some linear order, see e.g. Borie (2013). This algorithm is implemented in SageMath, class `IntegerVectorsModPermutationGroup`.
- For *some* groups $G$ the ranking and unranking are well understood.

  - If $G$ is trivial, then we have simply the ranking/unranking problem of nonnegative integer vectors having a fixed sum, and its solutions are well known.
  - If $G=S_k$, then the ball distributions are partitions of the integer $m$. The answers to [MO question "Computing the lexicographic indices of integer partition"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144891/computing-the-lexicographic-indices-of-integer-partition) describe a general unranking method that seems applicable: basically, consider values for $a_1$, and solve the *counting* problem for the remaining boxes with the remaining balls; then compare the count to your index, and either increment $a_1$, or fix it and solve the remaining boxes recursively.

However, even in some relatively simple special cases, like $G$ containing swaps of some boxes (and fixing some other boxes), or the boxes arranged as a [necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) (cyclic permutations) or a bracelet (cyclic permutations + reflection), I could not find a known algorithm. In special cases one can of course cook up a solution, but I'm wondering if the general case is solved somewhere. I would also like to hear of any interesting special cases that have been already solved, perhaps even implemented somewhere.

---

As mentioned, SageMath's `IntegerVectorsModPermutationGroup` is good for iterating; but it has simply the "default" rank and unrank functions that iterate until match. In fact even its cardinality function works by iterating: if we have $k=8$ boxes with no symmetry ($G$ is trivial), and $m=20$ balls, it takes something like 20 seconds to calculate $\lvert V \rvert = 888030$. (Of course, by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), it is $\binom{20+8-1}{20}$.)

My motivation for the question is that this is needed as a subroutine in my work with some classes of graphs (basically, I would like to find the $i$th way of adding some indistinguishable vertices at some locations in the graph, where the symmetry of the graph makes some solutions equivalent).

---

**Update (2.1.2024):** While wading through literature, I found the following opinion by Kopparty, Kumar and Saks 2016 (boldface mine):

> However, it seems that not all combinatorial counting arguments lead
> to efficient indexing algorithms. A prime example of this situation is
> when we have a finite group acting on a finite set, and the set we
> want to index is the set of orbits of the action. The associated
> counting problem can be solved using the Burnside counting lemma, and
> there **seems to be no general way to use this to get an efficient
> indexing algorithm.**

This somewhat dims my hopes of finding an existing efficient algorithm for the general case.  Hence I would be interested even in solved special cases.  (Kopparty et al. discuss the unranking of necklaces, which have circular symmetry.)

### References

*Borie, Nicolas*, [**Generation modulo the action of a permutation group**](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6261), Proceedings of the 25th international conference on formal power series and algebraic combinatorics, FPSAC 2013, Paris, France, June 24–28, 2013. Nancy: The Association. Discrete Mathematics & Theoretical Computer Science (DMTCS). Discrete Mathematics and Theoretical Computer Science. Proceedings, 767-778, electronic only (2013). [ZBL1294.05183](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1294.05183).

*Kopparty, Swastik; Kumar, Mrinal; Saks, Michael*, [**Efficient indexing of necklaces and irreducible polynomials over finite fields**](https://doi.org/10.4086/toc.2016.v012a007), Theory Comput. 12, Paper No. 7, 27 p. (2016). [ZBL1373.11080](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.11080).